# SubSonic 3.0.0.3 | SimpleRepository - bit field to bool property

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

is this a bug? my property of type bool from a bit field on SQL DB, always return (false), even though the value on the Database is (true).

although altering the property to true or false seems to be working, if you look at the database/table, the only problem is the fetching... return always "false"

I am using 
- subsonic-SubSonic-3.0-8a52a0913ac0b8542d5d041262046c497387223f Downloaded last July 30th
and I also try to get and download it today from here http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/tree/master click the Download which is seems to be the same as my previous download.
problem is not yet fixed.

But when I try the official released of 3.0.0.3, its working fine. but the problem there is the Update is not working.

please help =(

Comment: I applied the patch from below post : http://tinyurl.com/qos4b6
and seems to be working fine. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the current release: http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues/#issue/95

Comment: Not yet. The resolution is still being discussed

Comment: have any of you guys have a workaround? my app will go on production this friday, and QA already notice it =(

Comment: If you go to the link I sent, you can see someone has posted a patch (it adds an additional or condition for setting the value).